# Fill table with content of another table with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, copy

I have a grid of selectable divs on my page with attributes defining rows and columns. When I select some of them, the three dimensional table is created - lets name it table Copy.

When I select some other elements again the other three dimensional table is created - table Paste

After selecting two columns and two rows for the first time it will

```
   x,y - positions
   at1,at2,at2 - attributes for later copy

                             Table Copy
                          1                2
                0:[x,y,at1,at2,at3],[x,y,at1,at2,at3]
                1:[x,y,at1,at2,at3],[x,y,at1,at2,at3]
```

And after selecting three columns with three rows it will look like this

```
                             Table Copy
                          1                2
                0:[x,y,at1,at2,at3],[x,y,at1,at2,at3]
                1:[x,y,at1,at2,at3],[x,y,at1,at2,at3]

                             Table Paste
                  1                2                 3               
       0:[x,y,at1,at2,at3],[x,y,at1,at2,at3],[x,y,at1,at2,at3]
       1:[x,y,at1,at2,at3],[x,y,at1,at2,at3],[x,y,at1,at2,at3]
       2:[x,y,at1,at2,at3],[x,y,at1,at2,at3],[x,y,at1,at2,at3]
```

And now I need a function which simply fills the table paste with content from table copy

```
                             Table Paste
                  1                2                 3               
            0:[tabCopy[0][1]],[tabCopy[0][2]],[tabCopy[0][1]]
            1:[tabCopy[1][1]],[tabCopy[1][1]],[tabCopy[1][1]]
            2:[tabCopy[0][1]],[tabCopy[0][2]],[tabCopy[0][1]]
```

Of course there is a lot of possibilites of size of both arrays.

Table copy can have 4 rows, and table paste only 3. Then the fourth row of table Copy should be 'ignored'.

if table Copy in only 1 row 1 column, all records in table paste should look this same then

If table paste is only 1 row 1 column, it should take only the first record from table Copy.

I hope I described everything clearly :)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's see if I understood you...

```
function copyArrays(from, to) {
    for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < to.length;
         i++, j = (j + 1) % from.length) {
        if ((from[j] instanceof Array) &&
            (to[i] instanceof Array)) {
            copyArrays(from[j], to[i]);
        } else {
            to[i] = from[j];
        }
    }
}

var from = [["x", "y", "at1", "at2", "at3"],
            ["x", "y", "at1", "at2", "at3"],
            ["x", "y", "at1", "at2", "at3"],
            ["x", "y", "at1", "at2", "at3"]];

var to = [["+", "-", "123", "456", "789"],
          ["+", "-", "123", "456", "789"],
          ["+", "-", "123", "456", "789"],
          ["+", "-", "123", "456", "789"],
          ["+", "-", "123", "456", "789"],
          ["+", "-", "123", "456", "789"],
          ["+", "-", "123", "456", "789"],
          ["+", "-", "123", "456", "789"],
          ["+", "-", "123", "456", "789"]];
```

Then:

```
copyArrays(from, to);
```

will give you:

```
[["x", "y", "at1", "at2", "at3"], 
 ["x", "y", "at1", "at2", "at3"], 
 ["x", "y", "at1", "at2", "at3"], 
 ["x", "y", "at1", "at2", "at3"], 
 ["x", "y", "at1", "at2", "at3"], 
 ["x", "y", "at1", "at2", "at3"], 
 ["x", "y", "at1", "at2", "at3"], 
 ["x", "y", "at1", "at2", "at3"], 
 ["x", "y", "at1", "at2", "at3"]]
```